# Не забывайте ставить голос "за" на полезные ответы

Tags: обсуждение, нытьё, нормы-поведения

Сегодня занимался инспекцией кода. И у меня состоялся очень интересный разговор с одним товарищем. Я вижу, что код не его, но очень интересное и главное качественное решение, далее кратко

```
 - Откуда код?
 - На stackoverflow нашел...
 - Отлично, хорошее решение! Ты отблагодарил автора ответа?
 - Что? В смысле?
 - Ну, ты отметил что "Ответ полезен"
 - Нет
 - Почему?
 - Ну, там и так много голосов
 ...
```

Провел небольшую беседу с товарищем.

Хочу обратиться к участникам, которые находят и используют решения (помощь, инструменты, код) найденные на SO:

##### Если решение оказалось вам полезно - отметьте это, проголосуйте "за". Неважно, кто задал вопрос вы или не вы. Важно, что ответ решает вашу задачу. Примите за правило: воспользовался ⇒ оцени.

##### UPD

Как пример, оставлю вот этот односложный, но нужный для тех, кто погружается в `VCScode` (или кто меняет ОС и хоткеи будут другими) вопрос

[Как структурировать код в Visual Studio Code?](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/746590/209304)

33к просмотров, ответ только один и... всего 6 голосов "за".

Без умозаключений, просто, пример.

Comment: Те кто ищут и находят нужные ответы, и не голосуют за них (например пришли вообще из поисковика), скорее всего и на мету не заходят, и вряд ли увидят это обращение.

Comment: @insolor у тех, кто заходит на мету есть круг общения в профессиональной области. Сошлитесь, поднимите, добавьте активности, чтобы больше пользователей увидело

Comment: Изначально слишком узкий охват. Грубо говоря, на мету заходит 20 человек, у каждого, допустим, круг общения 30 человек, получится покрытие 600 человек. Чтобы покрыть больше, каждому придется приложить слишком много усилий при очень малом положительном выхлопе. Это не стоит того. Если бы такое объявление висело прямо на сайте, там где раньше было что-то типа "не стыдно задавать вопросы", охват был бы намного больше при меньших усилиях, и сразу на целевую аудиторию.

Comment: @insolor при некоторой активности тема попадает в "Важное на Мете", охват будет уже побольше. Хотя, я ничего сюда сильно не вкладывал. Заденет 600 человек -> ok, заденет 30, тоже не плохо. Другой площадки у меня все равно нет

Comment: Ну, как вариант, можно попросить модераторов поставить знак "важное", тогда автоматом появится в важном.

Comment: @insolor, так на сайте же есть такое уведомление? Особенно забавно, когда оно предлагает поставить плюс на странице со своим вопросом и с единственным ответом, который уже принят и которому уже стоит плюс.

Comment: Собственно, вот уже в «Обсуждаемое» вышло

Comment: @Qwertiy не видел такого уведомления. На мете вроде такого не было, на основном сайте - хз, редко пощу вопросы.

Comment: https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/1255542/373567 вот еще пример, архив с решением из ответа скачан 142 раза, но всего 5 голосов. :(

Comment: @aepot согласен, шикарный ответ +

Comment: Не у всех есть аккаунты на SO, не говоря уже о рейтинге, который нужен для голосования. Поэтому такая ситуация.

Answer (score 20, accepted):

Как по мне, голосовать нужно не только когда ты воспользовался чьим-то решение, но и в целом голосовать.
Думаю не все "гуляют" по SO и перебирают каждые вопросы, но думаю такие есть.
Вам же это ничего не стоит, по сути. Если вы изучили вопросы\ответы, то проголосуйте.

---

P.s. А ещё бесит "-" без какого-либо комментария.

> Минус без причины, признак дурачины

---

Немного офтоп, но тоже связано с ответами.
На SO множество вопросов, с не принятыми ответами, но явно какой-то из ответов решает проблему в вопросе.

Меня как-то посетила идея, а что если сообщество будет голосовать за правильный ответ, раз SO по сути база знаний.
Допустим не за каждый, а только если вопрос набрал голоса, да и ответ тоже.
Таким образом можно исключить "поднятие" вопросов ботом, к которым автор явно не вернётся.

Comment: "Минус без причины, признак дурачины"  --- все причины минусов написаны в справке. Не знание почему могут минусы поставить - вот признак дурачины

Comment: Думаете их всегда ставят по справке?

Comment: То есть значит по-вашему должны коментировать те, кто ставит минус не по справке?))

Comment: @АлексейШиманский  ***Голосуйте «Против», если сообщение кажется вам некачественным, недоработанным или явно неверным.*** В случае недоработанного автор минуса мог бы дать свой доработанный ответ, и уж тем более в случае явно неверного... Некачественный ответ — это что? С ошибками, или грамматическими ошибками, или как? В любом случае автору минуса :) следовало бы улучшить ситуацию, указав, что именно неверно или некачественно, чтобы дать возможность исправиться. Минус без комментария годится только в одном случае — при голосовании за закрытие, да и то лучше бы пояснить, за что именно...

Comment: @Harry писать комментарий что ответ неверен?)) А зачем отвечать заведомо неверным решением? ))

Comment: @АлексейШиманский А если человек искренне заблуждается? Ему надо пояснить, в чем ошибка.

Comment: @АлексейШиманский Раз вы так хорошо знаете, за что ставят минусы — поясните, за что я получил минусы, например, в ответах [1](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/1405019/195342), [2](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/1405014/195342), [3](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/1402091/195342) — ну, чтоб я не повторял свои ошибки :)

Comment: @Harry полагаю мне надо по всем ответам и вопросам на ruSO пройтись и всем написать?)) Сейчас только найду у себя отметку, что у меня это где-то в обязанности входит %)

Comment: @АлексейШиманский Нет, в ваши обязанности входит думать, прежде чем писать "*все причины минусов написаны в справке. Не знание почему могут минусы поставить - вот признак дурачины*", если вы не в состоянии определить, какая из причин действует в каждом конкретном случае (напомню, вы написали "**ВСЕ** причины", т.е. никаких иных нет).

Comment: @Harry то, что вы привели ссылки на свои ответы, говорит о том, что это **ВЫ** не в состоянии определить, а не я ¯\\_(ツ)_/¯

Comment: @АлексейШиманский В рамках ВАШИХ представлений - несомненно, не могу. Тем более что считаю их просто глупостью. А теперь - *вы* согласны, что написали глупость? Тогда дискуссия окончена. **ВЫ** считаете, что это не глупость, что все так, как вы написали? Доказывайте. Контрпримеры я привел.

Comment: @Harry, минимальная критика твоих ответов обычно выливается в километровые простыни нравоучений "как правильно пользоваться стэковерфлоу". Надо писать комментарий, надо писать правильный ответ, надо то, надо сё... Собственно прям как здесь в комментариях)) Никто тебе ничего не должен.

Comment: @ДжонниКэтсвилл Ну, поставьте минус комментарию молча :) Если комментарий по делу — указано на ошибку/описку/etc, я обычно просто пишу "спасибо" и исправляю ее. Иногда могу просто удалить ответ. Результат? Никто не вводится в заблуждение неверным ответом. А каков результат молчаливого минуса?

Comment: @Harry, окей, босс стэковерфлоу, спасибо, что разрешили.

Comment: @ДжонниКэтсвилл Но только для комментариев!

Comment: `Не знание почему могут минусы поставить  - вот признак дурачины` @АлексейШиманский я вот знаю почему минус _могут_ поставить, но почему в некоторых случаях их _ставят_ для меня загадка. Кроме того некоторые причины подразумевают комментарий, особенно если вопрошающий новичек и это, возможно, его первый вопрос.

Comment: @De.Minov На счёт минусов: мне иногда кажется, что его ставят, чтобы получить знак "Критик" или специально чтобы ответ у которого 0 баллов было выше по рейтингу чем -1. Потому что иногда оставляешь ответ и через пару секунд уже минус прилетает :)

Comment: @Harry та же ситуация, если меня поправят, исправляю ответ или удаляю вовсе, когда криво вопрос прочитал и ляпнул на скорости глупость какую нибудь. Я могу чего-то не знать и понимать. Я смирился с этим и работаю над этим:) но мне тут тоже минус прилетел непонятный,  крепко задумался,  хоть откомментировали что не так...

Comment: @Dmitry, аналогично, собственно по этому и написал об этом. Нужен фидбэк, чтобы получатель минуса понимал что сделал не так и как можно исправить ситуацию. Хотя опять же, даже если такое будет когда-то, то не факт, что после исправления автор минуса не уберёт его.

Answer (score 3):

Вроде бы такое уведомление уже есть, но только для тех, кто давно не посещал сайт:

[image: скриншот]

Comment: Ни разу не видел на ruSO =(

Comment: @Dmitry, слишком часто заходишь, либо слишком много репутации?

Comment: есть такое, 157 дней подряд... и не по разу

Comment: Есть ли пример данного уведомления для ruSO? Хорошее напоминание, особенно о том, что голосовать и за вопрос и за ответ. Вообще видно ли его в этой локализации, переведен ли

Comment: Я не знаю, как его получить. У меня на video production рейтинг 183. И я на него давным давно не заходил. Если я его сейчас открою снова, то этого сообщения не будет. И вчера я вопрос специально открывал не через сам сайт, а из гугла по запросу `ffmpeg crf cqp`. Как вариант, завести нового пользователя, месяц не заходить на сайт, а потом попробовать открыть вопрос по прямой ссылке. Но мне такими фокусами заниматься лень...